# Copy info from txt and paste in another vbscript

Tags: vbscript, copy-paste

I'm trying to copy a line of text from a .txt -> paste into another file and save. The code I have keeps giving me errors at the paste section. I am completely new at this and learning as I go. My main goal is to paste the info after `Host=` in another file. But I need to get this down first.

Here is my code so far

```
 ///OPEN FILE and READ
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\vnc\vnc.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close


' ///PASTE 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\vnc\testfile.vnc", 2)
objFileToWrite.Write strFileText
objFileToWrite.Close
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: line:14
Char:1
Permission denied

Comment: Does testfile.vnc exist? if not try CreateTextFile http://ss64.com/vb/filesystemobject.html

Comment: Yes it does, I've done both CreateTextFile and manually created it. Both give me the same error. I'm top admin of the computer so I know its not that.

Comment: There isn't a line 14 in the code snippet you posted. Which line is raising the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
'//OPEN FILE and READ
Set objFileToRead = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").OpenTextFile("C:\vnc.txt",1)
strFileText = objFileToRead.ReadAll()
objFileToRead.Close


' ///PASTE 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set objFileToWrite = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\vnc.vnc", 2)
objFileToWrite.Write strFileText
objFileToWrite.Close
```

The only difference I made was remove the subfolder, and put in the root of C:  The script worked.

I manually created both the source file and target file.  If both files exist, and are not locked (as if you had it open / locked in another application), then the permissions of that VNC folder must be the issue.

Comment: I found out what was creating the folder would override the folders permission putting it into Read-Only. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If still your file permission denied you to write then you have to do change the security of that file using right click of mouse, and update advanced setting.